# IPython parallel reference with map VS apply

Tags: reference, parallel-processing, ipython

I can't get parallel reference working when using map and dict like argument.

```
from IPython import parallel
from IPython.parallel import Client
from IPython.parallel import Reference

rc = Client()
dview = rc.direct_view()
dview.block = True

dview['l'] = [0, 1]
kws = [{'l': Reference('l')}]
def second(kws):
    l = kws['l']
    return l[1]

dview.apply(second, kws[0])
```

Returns:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

But:

```
dview.map(second, kws)
```

Returns:

```
TypeError: 'Reference' object does not support indexing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the unserialization does not handle nested structures well. You can see this for yourself like this:

```py
from IPython.core.display import display
from IPython.kernel.zmq.serialize import serialize_object, unserialize_object
from IPython.parallel import Reference
l = 5
ref = Reference('l')
kws = [dict(l=ref)]
display(unserialize_object(serialize_object(kws), g=globals()))
# outputs ([{'l': <Reference: 'l'>}], [])
display(unserialize_object(serialize_object(kws[0]), g=globals()))
# outputs ({'l': 5}, [])
```

I'm not an IPython developer but looking around the code I found a very simple way to fix it. In `ipykernel/pickleutil.py` (or `IPython/utils/pickleutil.py`), there is a dictionary that maps types to unserialization methods:

```py
uncan_map = {
    CannedObject : lambda obj, g: obj.get_object(g),
}
```

Simply adding `dict` fixes the problem:

```py
uncan_map = {
    CannedObject : lambda obj, g: obj.get_object(g),
    dict : uncan_dict,
}
```

I will make a pull request for the ipykernel project referencing this question.